# How can I receive files from client as private message using stomp over spring boot websockets?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have written the following codes to receive private text message :

```
 @MessageMapping("/message.private.{username}")
  public void userSpecificMessage(@DestinationVariable String username, @Payload String 
    payload, Principal principal) throws Exception {
        String username = principal.getName();
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username, "/queue/message", new Test(payload));
    }
```

How can I receive files sent by client in this method? Can @Payload be used to receive files message? Please help me out and any links related to sending files over stomp and spring websocket will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?